# Sending email to contact from automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, automationstudio

We are using salesforce reports to send email to contact from automation studio. the process seems to working fine i can see status as sent under tracking but no email was sent out.  What might be the issue?

Comment: Did you check the email deliverability ?

Comment: Search Deliverability in search bar and make sure that access level is set to All Emails.Also Search Test Deliverability and put your email address there and send an  email and check if you are getting the email or not

Comment: Hello @Samir i did check email deliverability and i tested out with my email address, i am getting emails to my inbox.

Comment: @Josyula - How many emails you received?

Comment: Hello @Samir I received 32 emails as we have 32 IP addresses

Comment: Is `Available For Use` checkbox is checked on the template being used to send the email?

Answer (score 0):

**Testing Deliverability**

Available in: **All Editions except Database.com**

**User Permissions Needed**
To test email deliverability:   “Modify All Data”
Salesforce sends email from 52 different IP addresses. If your organization blocks any of these IP addresses, users might not receive all email sent from Salesforce.

To verify your organization can receive email from every Salesforce IP address:
Click **Your Name | Setup | Email Administration | Test Deliverability.**
Enter your business email address.
Click **Send**. Salesforce simultaneously sends a test message from all 48 IP addresses to your business email address. Each test message specifies the IP address from which it was sent.
Check your business email account to make sure it received all 48 test messages.
If you received less than 48 test messages, your organization's email administrator must whitelist the Salesforce IP ranges on your organization's email server. Whitelisting an IP address allows the email server to receive email from an IP address that might otherwise be blocked. The Salesforce IP ranges are:

> 96.43.144.64 to 96.43.144.65
>
> 96.43.148.64 to 96.43.148.65
>
> 182.50.78.64 to 182.50.78.79
>
> 204.14.232.64 to 204.14.232.79
>
> 204.14.234.64 to 204.14.234.79

**Note**
If your organization activates email relaying, your email administrator only needs to whitelist the IP addresses Salesforce uses for email relaying

> (96.43.144.65, 96.43.148.65, 182.50.78.65, 204.14.232.65, and
> 204.14.234.65).

For information on email relaying, see Setting Up Email Relaying.
Salesforce.com maintains separate IP addresses for inbound and outbound email. The IP addresses used for outbound email don’t accept inbound email connections.

Please mark this as a best answer if your query  is resolved so othre also get help from this thread in future.

You can also go through this [Document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Troubleshooting-Email-Delivery-problems&language=en_US&type=1) to troubleshooting Email Delivery problems